# Neo4j Retreival order @ SDN

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Ex:
  @RelatedTo
  Set resSet = new LinkedHashSet();

After inserting "resSet" in to Neo4j DB. What is the order of "resSet" when we get from database.

In my scenario, order of insertion and order of retreival is quite opposite.

Is there any way of retrieving the nodes in the same order they got inserted.

Answer (score 0):

The order is not guaranteed. As generally in Neo4j by default.

If you need a guaranteed order use a repository method with a Cypher query or a `Sort` parameter.